# How retrieve name of attached files of a workitem starting from an instance of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Workitem

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

How retrieve names of attached files of a workitem starting from an instance of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Workitem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sample to retrieve the name of attachments from a specific work item:

With Nuget package [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) installed.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;

namespace RetrieveAttachmentName
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var u = new Uri("http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection");
            var c = new VssClientCredentials();
            int workitemid = 78;
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(u, c);
            tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
            WorkItemStore wistore = tpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
            WorkItem wi = wistore.GetWorkItem(workitemid);

            var file1 = wi.Attachments[0].Name;
            var file2 = wi.Attachments[1].Name;
            //var file3 = wi.Attachments[2].Name;
            //...

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}\n{1}", file1, file2));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]